# PIL Python: A rounded rectangle image converted to numpy array is all zeros

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
a_rect = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 100))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(a_rect)
draw.rounded_rectangle((0, 0, 400, 100),
                       outline=None,
                       radius=75,
                       fill='blue'
                       )
a_rect
```

[image]

When i convert the above image to array using `np.asarray(a_rect)` I get following:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       ...,
...
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

This is not the expected behaviour, I am unable to manipulate this array or apply animation to it due to it being all zeros.

Comment: It's not all zeros.  When numpy displays a large array, it shows you the first 3 rows and columns, and the last 3 rows and columns.  The dots do NOT mean that everything in between is zero.  Things are working just fine -- go do your analysis.

Comment: Try printing `np.mean(YOURARRAY)` and `np.max(YOURARRAY)`